# Should I use mod_rewrite for my site's URLs?

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

My site currently handles URL's like this...

```
/?p=home  
/?p=profile&userid=1  
/?p=users.online  
/?p=users.online&page=23  
/?p=mail.inbox  
/?p=mail.inbox&page=12
```

... and so on, there is probably at least 120-150 different pages, on my site a page is built like this,

**index.php** includes a main **config file** which then includes **function/class files** into it
**index.php** then includes a **header file**
**index.php** then includes the **page file** which is from the url ?p=pagename
**index.php** then includes a **footer file**

That is how every page on my site is compiled, through the index page like that and I have been considering/thinking about cleanning up the URL's as I am re-writing/restructuring most of my sites code right now, it's the perfect time to do it if I am going to do it.  What I mean by cleanning up the URL's is using mod-rewrite so the URL structure above would look like this instead...

```
/home
/users/1  //user ID might switch to use username as well
/users/online
/users/online/23 or /users/online/page/23
/mail/inbox
/mail/inbox/12
```

---

So first of all is there any downfalls to doing this, does it create a lot more processing work since it is using mod_rewrite?

Also would it be hard to write the regex or whatever is needed to match the file names in the format that I show above, I listed only a few of the pages but there would be at least 100 different URL pages I have blogs, bulletins, forums, all kinds of stuff

Comment: No answer, but from your users' perspective, *please* do this: Any URL with a query string is uncacheable according to the spec. So your current structure forces a re-GET every time.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: According to what specification? Please prove that assertion.

Comment: @Gumbo: The HTTP specification, Section 13.9 for example - http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html

Comment: This applies to HTTP 1.0 and to cases where no explicit caching information is provided. If query strings are supposed to act as no-cache indicators, then you might want to tell that to a few browser vendors out there.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: You name it: “[…] caches MUST NOT treat responses to such URIs as fresh *unless* the server provides an explicit expiration time.”

Comment: @Gumbo: Precisely. Check your headers; are *you* supplying explicit expiration times? If you are, good on you and mazel tov.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely. That's one of Apache's main purposes, so it's been designed to do it very efficiently. In fact, I'd emplore you to use that method.

1. It makes cleaner URLs for visitors
2. It's fantastic for SEO
3. It makes the website more professional
4. It makes it easier for users to guess URLs if they are trying to find a certain page without actually traversing through your site ti find it.

There are **no** downfalls, and a ton of advantages to using that URL structure. Go for it!

Comment: Oops. The "nope" was an answer to his question "does it create more processing work?" Fixed - thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer, 1 thing I have been uncertain of is many of my sections I have paging like page=12 so I didn't know if this woyuld cause a problem when there is no paging for that page, for example if you are on page 1 then it does not show any paging data in the url

Comment: jason: Get help with your specific regex problems when you experience them. Go get implementing now... Besides, it's EASY to go from blah/whatever/p# to your query string...